# How to write interruptable methods

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have a method which, conceptually, looks something like:

```
Object f(Object o1) {
    Object o2 = longProcess1(o1);
    Object o3 = longProcess2(o2);
    return longProcess3(o3);
}
```

Where the processes themselves might also be compound:

```
Object longProcess1(Object o1) {
    Object o2 = longSubProcess1(o1);
    return longSubProcess2(o2);
}
```

And so forth, with the different processes potentially sitting in different modules. Most of the processes are long because they are computationally expensive, not IO-bound.

So far so good, but now I want `f` as a whole to be interruptable. [The recommended Java way to do that](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) is to periodically check for the interrupted flag with `Thread.interrupted()`. It's pretty straightforward, but it can quickly become cumbersome if I need to change my methods to something like:

```
Object f(Object o1) {
    Object o2 = longProcess1(o1);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
    Object o3 = longProcess2(o2);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
    return longProcess3(o3);
}

Object longProcess1(Object o1) {
    Object o2 = longSubProcess1(o1);
    if (Thread.interrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
    return longSubProcess2(o2);
}

...
```

Now, **I do understand the rational for working like that** - it allows me to better control when the InterruptedException (for example) will be thrown, avoiding leaving objects in inconsistent states - but **I am curious to know if there's a more elegant way of doing that***.

* In Java, not AspectJ, which I guess is very appropriate here but I'm stuck with Java.

Comment: I'd be worried about deadlocks with code that contains threads that ref each other.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an interface and a Dynamic proxy:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public static <T> T wrap(Class<T> intf, final T impl) {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, new Class<?>[] {intf},
                new InvocationHandler() {
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }
                return method.invoke(impl, args);
            }
        });
        return intf.cast(proxy);
    }
}

interface Processes {
    Object longProcess1(Object o);
    ...
}

public class ProcessesImpl implement Processes {
    Processes self = Wrapper.wrap(Processes.class, this);

    public Object f(Object o1) {
        Object o2 = self.longProcess1(o1);
        Object o3 = self.longProcess2(o2);
        return self.longProcess3(o3);
    }

    public Object longProcess1(Object o1) {
        Object o2 = self.longSubProcess1(o1);
        return self.longSubProcess2(o2);
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but still a bit cumbersome. I would need to add a field for all relevant classes, and qualify many method calls. The resulting methods *are* more elegant, though, I'll give you that!

Answer (score 0):

Did I get this right that you sequentially run methods that are at the same nesting level? If so, why not just implement your computation methods as `java.lang.Runnable` instances, organize them into lists and start them in the loop? Then you would have only one place with `Thread.interrupted()` check.

You might consider using `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` to facilitate the control over computation tasks.

Updated with an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CompoundProcess> subProcesses1 = new ArrayList<CompoundProcess>();
        subProcesses1.add(new CompoundProcess() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Process 1.1");
            }
        });
        subProcesses1.add(new CompoundProcess() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Process 1.2");
            }
        });

        List<CompoundProcess> subProcesses2 = new ArrayList<CompoundProcess>();
        subProcesses2.add(new CompoundProcess() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Process 2.1");
            }
        });
        subProcesses2.add(new CompoundProcess() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Process 2.2");
            }
        });

        List<CompoundProcess> processes1 = new ArrayList<CompoundProcess>() {};
        processes1.add(new CompoundProcess(subProcesses1));
        processes1.add(new CompoundProcess(subProcesses2));

        CompoundProcess process = new CompoundProcess(processes1);
        process.run();
    }


    static class CompoundProcess implements Runnable {

        private List<CompoundProcess> processes = new ArrayList<CompoundProcess>();

        public CompoundProcess() {
        }

        public CompoundProcess(List<CompoundProcess> processes) {
            this.processes = processes;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (Runnable process : processes) {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("The processing was interrupted");
                } else {
                    process.run();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, the processes are in many different places - I tried to demonstrate it by showing that `longProcess1` is in itself compound, maybe I wasn't clear enough - so I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Once processes at the same level are run sequentially it does not matter much that they are started in different places. I updated my answer with an example. You can nest processes to the level you want.